# How to find & replace in all columns with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

In PowerBI when i use find/replace it produces the following:
= Table.ReplaceValue(Custom2,"-999","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"})

But I'd like to replace -999 in all columns, not just Column1.
I'd also like to not have to define a list of all the column names.
Is there a way to do this find replace in all columns with a wildcard or something?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: [Easy way to rename multiple columns using either a text function or find & replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74935863/easy-way-to-rename-multiple-columns-using-either-a-text-function-or-find-repla)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Table.ColumnNames()`. This generates a dynamic list of column names for the table without you having to manually define a list.

`= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Table Name","-999","",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames((#"Table Name" as table)))`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`Table.ColumnNames()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-columnnames) function.

For example, we can transform this table:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x |
| 2 | b | y |
| 3 | c | z |

In to this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x |
| 2 |  | y |
| 3 | c | z |

By using this code:

```fs
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUUoE4gqlWJ1oJSMgKwmIK8E8YyArGYirlGJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col1 = _t, col2 = _t, col3 = _t]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"b","",Replacer.ReplaceText,Table.ColumnNames(Source))
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```